# Parsing a string with multiple variations

Tags: java, routes

I am curious as to what a better way to deal with this is, I wanted to challenge my self and see if I could break up, in a `HashMap` of `key,value` (or `String, String`), a string that could come back in almost any format.

the string in question is:

`/user/2/update?updates=success`

Thats right, a url request for a server. The issue - as we all know this could be any thing, it could come back in any form. I wanted to break it up so that it would look like:

```
Controller => user
action => update
params => ??? (theres a 2, a update=success ... )
```

**Obviously** The above is **not a real** java object.

But you get the idea.

**What do you need? what have you done? what are you trying to do?**

What I want to do is map this to a controller and action while passing in the parameters along the way. But i need to separate this up making sure to specify each step what is what.

What I have done is:

```
private Filter parseRoute(String route){
    String[] parsedRoute = route.split("[?:/=]");
    Filter filter = new Filter(parsedRoute);
    return filter;
}
```

Splits on any thing that is in the url (note, `:` would be something like `/user:id/update`
so: `user/2/update` ... )

I then attempted to do:

```
public class Filter {

    private HashMap<String, String> filterInfo;

    public Filter(String[] filteredRoute){
        if(filteredRoute.length > 0){
            filterInfo.put("Controller", filteredRoute[0]);

        }else{
            throw new RoutingException("routes must not be empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not going to work as I expected it to...As there are too many variables at play.
including parameters before the action (those would just be used to search for that user), their could be nested routes, so multiple `controller/action/controller/action` ..

How would you deal with this? What would you suggest? How could you get around this? Should you just do something like:

`route(controller, action, params, template);` ? (`template` lets you render a jsp). if so how do you deal with the `?update=success`

I am using HttpServer to set up the basics. But I am now lost. I am trying to keep routing as generic and "do what ever you want we will map it to the right controller, action and pass in the parameters" but I think I bit off more then I can chew.

I have looked at both spark and spring framework, and decided that the route you pass, we will map to a xml file to find the controller and action, I just need the data structure in place to do that ...

So I am looking to back up and still go with "pass me something, ill map it out."

Comment: That's going to be a real challenge, since HTTP parameters actually form a `Multiset` just by themselves. "/user/2/update?updates=success&updates=success&updates=fail"

Comment: I would use an existing HTTP parser (probably Apache's), because this is a classic non-trivial task which has been solved many times.

Comment: are there any examples of using apaches tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use the [URL](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/URL.html) from apache,

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.URL url = null;
try {
  url = new org.apache.tomcat.util.net.URL("/user/2/update?updates=success");
  // ... do some stuff with it...
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

java.net.URI may help you.

you can get your path by getPath()

and get all of your query by getQuery(),then you can split the query by `=` to name value pairs.

```
    URI uri = new URI("/user/2/update?updates=success");
    // /user/2/update
    System.out.println("path is " + uri.getPath());
    // updates=success
    System.out.println("query is  " + uri.getQuery());
```

Comment: multiple queries, multiple paths, how would that work with:

`/library/6/books/10/chapter/6/paragraph/2/update?update=sucess?someparam=fff?someOtherParam?=fff`

Comment: multiple query are separate with '&' not '?',you can split by '&' first,and then use '=' to separate name and value